# PHP APC Progress Bar

Tags: php, file-upload, mamp, apc

Post Updated: After commentors advice.

Index.php

```
<?php
$id = uniqid("");
?>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="frame.php" target="upload_iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" id="progress_key" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="upload_iframe" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
</iframe>
```

frame.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['progress_key'])) {
    echo "hey1";
    $status = apc_fetch('upload_'.$_POST['progress_key']);
    echo $status['current']/$status['total']*100;
}
echo "hey2";
?>
```

Still doesnt work :(, I dont even get POST form data in frame. Where am i going so wrong?

Regards.

Comment: What are your php.ini values for `apc.rfc1867_prefix` and `apc.rfc1867_name`?  The value of the `name` attrbute in the hidden field should correspond to `apc.rfc1867_name` and the prefix of your `apc_fetch` call should correspond to `apc.rfc1867_prefix`.

Comment: In MAMP, i have selected APC from preferences, and in conf > PHP5 > php.ini updated: 
apc.rfc1867 = on
apc.max_file_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the APC file upload mechanism, you need to add an additional parameter to your form that identifies the file that's being uploaded, and is the key for your `apc_fetch`.

`<?php $id = uniqid(time()); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" id="myUniProgressKey"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>`

As the file is uploaded the value in the key `upload . $id` will contain the info you need to display the progress bar.  Easiest way to get to is to ajax poll the server, using the `apc_fetch` call you have.  This dictates that your upload page needs to not refresh the current page the user is on.  I've used an `iframe` in the past that kicks off an interval to poll the server.  Once the upload is complete, you're able to show a nice complete message in the same iframe.

Comment: Please help me with the updated code in the post, made a few changes still doesnt work. http://pastie.org/1500354 Highly Appreciated Help. :)

Comment: One way to test this is to then hardcode your progress key, set up a separate page that dumps the output of `apc_fetch`, using your hardcoded progress key.  Initiate a large file upload, and then refresh the test page to see what's actually coming back.  Also, have you implemented the ajax bit of this?  You are aware that you need to implement the actual progress bar itself? apc will track the progress of your upload, but it won't output a progress bar for you.

Comment: Okay, i really cannot follow whavt you have suggested, can you give a small code example or something? It would be really helpful. And right now my biggest problem is that i dont even get the post value! Also I guess my ajax is implemented, with the present  code and there are two different pages in the pastie example i gave you one loads in iframe. :) I know without JS it wont be a bar but i am not even looking for that, if i can get the $status, i can implement the bar then.. :)

Comment: Your code looks basically correct, but this is pretty complex, so you should probably do some debugging.  Have you tried `var_dump`ing the `$_POST` array?

Comment: Okay the code loads up and i get the values but always the status current is equal to status total 
Code: http://pastie.org/1505616